# Rent contract say that pets are not allowed. Possible repercussions if bringing the pet anyway?

Tags: rent, pets, austria

We are two living in an apartment in Tirol where the contract says that there are no pets allowed. Now, for an unrelated reason, I need to have my cat with me. My roommate is ok with having him here.

I asked my landlord if he could allow me to have him but he said no.

If I decide to bring him anyways, and my landlord finds out, what are the possible repercussions?

Things to keep in mind:

- I'm too much emotionally attached to him to give him away.
- I don't have any friend near who could have him, nor I would give him to an animal shelter.

Comment: A possible second option: see if you can get an early lease termination from your landlord, and move somewhere that allows pets. There should be pet hotels that can house your cat while you work this out if there's timing issues.

Comment: Does your landlord a private person or a company? Does he live near you? Is that a kind of shared two floor house? Depending on how much this affects him, the reaction will be different. But you could have rented a pet-friendly place to start with.

Comment: Other possible repercussion (which I have personally observed): landlord arranges for your cat to disappear, permanently.

Comment: Male or female cat?

Comment: Does austria have a similar program to The united state's emotional support animal?

Comment: The foundation of contract law is to be honest and with integrity.  A cat in an apartment, according to current studies, leaves clinically significant allergens even 30 years afterwards.  Some landlords are aware of this, and there are some tenants who suffer significant allergies because of the persistence of allergens.

Comment: @QuoraFeans it's a real estate company

Comment: @DatsunZ1 that's what I wish to know

Comment: @Harper male cat. Old, lazy and a heavy sleeper, so he wouldn't generate any chaos as he isn't very active

Comment: @JohnKirtThird a legel contract entered into freely is binding. You may be held responsible for any costs deemed needed should you ignore your obligations.

Comment: @MarkJohnson not all contracts are legal. If a contract has a clause which the law doesn't abide, that makes that clause invalid. To make a ridiculous example, if you sign a contract that says that if you can't pay you have to amputee your leg, although you agreed on it in the contract, it's illegal so the state law denies your obligation to comply with that clause. If there is a law that says, like England, that it is forbidden to forbid small pets without a valid excuse, then that clause would became invalid. That's what I'm asking for

Comment: @JohnKirtThird your answer is no, this is a common condition in many contracts and (in general) no court has stated otherwise. In my case this condition was contained  in the original draft of the rent contract and I agreed to it only after it was removed.

Answer (score 24):

You signed a contract where you agree to not have pets and the landlord agreed to let you live there. If you decide to not follow your end of the deal, the landlord might not either. In simple terms, you can get evicted. There is probably a clause in the contract to the effect of "you will get evicted if you don't follow these rules".

Depending on contract and local law, you may also be fined, forced to remove the pet, or have your security deposit withheld. One reason landlords don't want pets is that pets leave odors and fur in the apartment, requiring costly cleaning. Not to mention some cats *love* tearing up the carpeting and otherwise destroying the property. Thus the deposit is used to "repair the damage" caused by the pet. Some landlords charge an additional pet fee for tenants with animals, so if you secretly keep a pet you are cheating them out of the fee as well.

If you want the cat for several months or more, then you probably shouldn't try to hide it from the landlord. There is a big risk you will be discovered and suffer repercussions. The landlord may also refuse to renew your lease later. In theory, and depending on your tenant, you could claim that the cat was there for a day and it will be removed right away. But as I said, landlords are concerned more about the damage to their property than policing you, so once the landlord gets suspicious (probably already happened since you asked him about it) they could inspect the place and demand you pay for damage regardless of how long the cat was supposedly there.

Well being of the cat is unlikely to create an exception to the contract. However, you could have some recourse by claiming that the cat is an emotional support animal and vital to *your* well being. I am not familiar with the process for this in Austria, but presumably it will involve paperwork from a psychologist verifying the fact. Simply saying you really like the cat and don't want to give it away will not be a sufficient reason - you initially agreed to not have pets, so it can be argued that you should not have taken one in to begin with.

I love cats too, but you probably shouldn't do it if your landlord already told you no. You could end up in a situation where you are forced to put the cat in a shelter, which wouldn't be good for the cat. If your landlord won't budge, your best option is to move somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure if the "renew the lease" part is relevant.  Tenants rights are pretty strong in some European countries, which I believe includes Austria, and landlord may well have to go to court to get the tenant evicted (in many countries, which I believe includes Austria, rental contracts do not have an ending date so they are not "renewed").

Comment: In addition to @gerrit 's point, there may be consumer protection laws that prevent no-pet clauses. E.g. in the UK such a clause is not valid. Consent must not be unreasonably be withheld. Arguments such as "pets cause damage" may not be sustainable if the tenant is willing to pay for such damage (e.g. via a larger deposit).

Comment: @gerrit In Austria, there are both limited and unlimited contracts, and there are a number of situations that would "upgrade" a limited to an unlimited one.

Comment: I don't see why the OP could be evicted... in most European countries only *very specific* circumstances can trigger an eviction (e.g. not paying rent is a common one). The contract might explicitly state that some actions/violations can trigger an eviction. But if the contract doesn't state that having a pet is a violation that triggers an eviction chances are the OP would simply pay a fine + damages (if the cat does something). IMHO the OP is looking for an answer citing Austria's laws to determine what could happen not a general advice based on an other continent's laws.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't know anything about Austra or "most European countries", but in the UK at least, you can do no-fault evictions (they are known as Section 21 evictions), any time after the initial term of the tenancy agreement has expired, giving the tenant 2 months notice from the next rent due date. I agree that the advice should be Austria-specific to be useful.

Comment: Is the max damage typically a total loss of deposit? I'd imagine that a hypoallergenic cleaning could put the cleaning cost over the cost of the deposit, so who pays in that case?

Comment: @JBentley In my experience, UK is quite unusual within Europe in that respect.

Comment: @Mars If the tenant has damaged the property in violation of the contract, the tenant is liable for the *whole* of the costs the landlord is put to.  The deposit just makes it easier for the landlord to get hold of these damages.

Comment: @JBentley Can you give a cite for "in the UK a no-pets clause is not valid"?  We (landlords) were certainly offered it as an option in 2016 by our agent.

Comment: Downvoted. This answer has no sources and is quite possibly wrong.

Comment: @MartinBonner [Link 1](https://www.haboth.com/can-landlords-say-no-pets-uk/) [Link 2](https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2016/10/04/tenant-penalties-breaching-tenancy-rules-pets/). Note the rest of my comment too - it is outright refusal that is invalid. A landlord can still say no to pets if it reasonable to do so (for example there is no mitigation for potential damage). On the other extreme, if you refuse permission for a goldfish, it is quite unlikely to be enforceable. On a more general note, agents in the UK are unregulated and often unqualified, so their legal knowledge is often lacking

Comment: @JBentley We never got to sign a no-pets lease, I think our agents were clued up enough that it would have been a lawful lease.

Comment: Damage to the landlord could be beyond the scope of damage to the apartment.  I am asthmatically allergic to cat urine.  Any cat urine near me can cause anaphylaxis (swelling of the throat, leading to not being able to have air move beyond my throat - risking death).  If this were my tenant (of which I have none), I could sue for personal damages beyond the physical damage to the property.  Just because you feel you want the cat does not give you the right to assume the reasons behind the rule given by the landlord and then override them.

Comment: @MartinBonner Note that you can have a lawful clause with wording such as "The Tenant is not to keep pets at the property without the prior consent of the Landlord, such consent not to be unreasonably withheld". Whereas a clause such as "The Tenant is not to keep pets at the property" could be challenged in court. It's possible your agent offered you something similar to the former.

Comment: @JBentley Yes, my point is: rent contracts are usually regulated by specific laws. They are not "just a contract" because they deal with the living place of a person and thus most jurisdictions provide a lot more protections to the person paying the rent to live in that place. This answer assumes that "rent contracts are just contracts", which is generally not the case in EU and many other places.

Answer (score 13):

The legal repercussion is that you could be evicted for breach of contract. The courts would not order you to give away the cat. What you should do, rather than waiting for this to melt down to a court case where you would not like the outcome, is instead to negotiate an accommodation with the landlord. You want something, so don't expect to get it for free. For example, the landlord might be willing to allow the cat if you pay more money. If you offered a substantial increase in rent in your initial negotiations and the landlord still said no, that might signal the futility of negotiation.

If this matter is non-negotiable, then the ball is in the landlord's court, to get you legally evicted for violating the lease terms. This will cost him, and he may decide that it is not worth doing. However, if he has a severe cat allergy and you have by bringing the animal into the unit caused him greater-than-usual harm, he would probably less inclined to pursue the increased-rent option.

Comment: If Austria is anything like Germany, then in all likelihood the landlord may well be a large company owning thousands of apartment buildings.

Comment: @gerrit If the landlord is a large company, in my experience, they will still be willing to negotiate to keep an otherwise unproblematic tenant, rather than risk having to evict and have a more problematic one.

Comment: Note that if there are other harmful effects that result from having the cat (e.g. the landlord, or anyone who lives in the same building, has a severe cat allergy, and you cause them distress/harm), the OP could be held liable for that harm, whatever it is.

Answer (score 4):

At least in Austria and Germany, banning cats in rented apartments is quite a complex issue. [See here.](http://www.uni-salzburg.at/fileadmin/multimedia/Privatrecht/MEDIEN-SEITE/PDF/ZAK_2008_20_ENDG.PDF) Generally banning them seems not to be possible, as they usually don't bother other tenants and you can easily restore your apartment when leaving, should the cat damage it.

> possible repercussions?

Well, don't expect any goodwill on other matters from your landlord.

Maybe your cat is annoying and does get banned. Maybe you get sued, either successfully or not.  Maybe your landlord is fine after seeing your cat behaves normally. Maybe he will never notice. Honestly, no one can tell.

Comment: "You can easily restore your apartment when the cat damages it". That's called nose blindness, same way smokers don't think their house and stuff smells like smoke.  However any other human will find the place repulsive. I've lived in a house where the carpets, pad AND subfloor all had to be replaced.  The enzyme liquid is useless.

Comment: I have to agree with @Harper on this. Unfortunately it isnt terribly easy. Im severely allergic to cats and basically have in the past had to have wallpaper, paint and sometimes even drywall replaced, carpets and under-carpets replaced, and vents professionally cleaned, this often costs many thousands. Not to mention all other hard surfaces bleached and steamed and couldn't even think about keeping any appliances, fixtures or furniture that were there before...

Comment: @knallfrosch, could you share what part of the document should I look into? (You linked a 21 pages doc withouth saying what I should look there)